# BigDecimal assign operator

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a problem with assigning one big decimal value to another

I am trying such as creating one temp big decimal and add 0 to another big decimal

```
BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(0);
dropStartValue =  temp.add(newCounterValue);
```

However, I only want simply do the operation below on big decimals:

```
dropStartValue = newCounterValue
```

Comment: What language is this? Java?
Also, what type does "newCounterValue" belong to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified the type of either `dropStartValue` or `newCounterValue`. If they're both BigDecimals, then this should be fine:

```
dropStartValue = newCounterValue;
```

Note that although that's just making both variables refer to the same object, it's safe because `BigDecimal` itself is immutable.

If that's not working for you, please give details of what problems you're seeing (exceptions? compile-time errors?).

Comment: And for the OP, some documentation: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Java ans newCounterValue is an integer type or a box thereof, `dropStartValue = new BigDecimal(newCounterValue);` should do what you want.

Comment: I thought that originally - but BigDecimal.add doesn't take ints etc, so I suspect newCounterValue is another BigDecimal...

Comment: @Jon: Sure it does: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(int)